# Loopback extending built in User model issues

Tags: mongodb, models, loopbackjs, extending, built-in

I am inheriting the builtin User model in my own Customer model. The Customer model is having extra parameters like first-name, last-name etc. To create an User and Customer I am using the following code:

```
// create a Customer
        User.create({
            email: email,
            password: userPassword,
            cellnumber: cellDetails.cellnumber
        },
            function (error, userDet) {
```

I get an id in response to this call: 59c4c5845dc8de4730645963. But when I am trying to get the account by id i.e. accounts/{id} and pass it the above id, it gives the following error:

```
the "Unknown \"customer\" id \"59c4c5845dc8de4730645963\"."
```

So this means that id of the User model and Customer model are somehow not same. How do I resolve this ? Also, in the mongo db database all the properties are getting visible under the User model and not under the Customer model. What am I doing wrong here ? Could anyone let me know.

Thanks

Comment: So can I use Customer.login() or Account.login() to login the user ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you should create like this: `Account.create({ email, password, ... })` , using the `Account` model rather than `User` model.

You should use the model you created document with, `Account` in this case. The thing is, each model works only with it's own MongoDB collection and they are isolated from each other.